# Kubuntu cant add new ssh network folder

Tags: ssh, kubuntu, dolphin-file-manager

I'm trying to add a remote ssh network folder in Kubuntu 11.04.

I can connect to this remote server via konsole ssh

```
: ssh 10.3.140.111
```

However when I try and add a "new network folder" from the network section of dolphin I get the following error message

> Unable to connect to server.  Please check your settings and try
>   again.

Trying to connect using konsole and dolphin...

```
: dolphin sftp://user@10.3.140.111:22/home/user
```

gives me another error:

> Connection to host The host key for this server was not found, but
>   another type of key exists.
>
> An attacker might change the default server key to confuse your client
>   into thinking the key does not exist.
>
> Please contact your system administrator.
>    is broken.

I can't seem to find any help for this issue, any ideas?

Answer (score 6):

1. close Dolphin
2. open terminal and enter:
    `$ ssh-keygen -R 10.3.140.111`
3. open Dolphin and enter into the address bar:
    `sftp://user@10.3.140.111:22/home/user`
    (the port number is optional since it is the default 22 in this case)
4. Click "yes" to the dialog that comes up

Comment: If you have a non-standard port number on the remote server, the IP address is not enough. You need to include it in step #2 (brackets and quotes are all part of the command): `ssh-keygen -R '[10.3.140.111]:22200'`

Answer (score 5):

Remove the `known_hosts` file:

```
user@nixbox:~$ cd ~/.ssh
user@nixbox:~/.ssh$ ls
known_hosts
wolf@nixbox:~/.ssh$ rm known_hosts
```

Then try to add folder again and click 'yes' for the key. The file will automatically be recreated.

Comment: This removes *all* keys, not just the problematic one.

Answer (score 4):

use fish://user@10.3.140.111:22/home/user

instead of sftp and it'll work just great.

you can also set up your ~/.ssh/config to store ip, username, port etc so then you can just type fish://myserver/ in dolphin

Comment: Don't know why this answer is downvoted. I tried and it works. Just choose `fish` not sftp in the `Add Network Folder` dialog.

Comment: Worked for me (the other option not involving removing all keys did not), now can anyone explain why?

Comment: FISH is a different (but very much alike) protocol than SFTP. More info here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Files_transferred_over_shell_protocol My guess is that FISH has a different preference for SSH keys than SFTP? but that's all I can come up with

Comment: FISH didn't work for me and the error message was vague and unhelpful, SFTP did work for me after fiddling with my known_hosts file.